# Is there any way to add 3rd party programs / apps to this agent

Tags: azure, build-pipeline

As on the image it says "The following software is installed on machines in ....." 
Is there any way to install my own or any other 3rd party softwares to install to this server.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosted agent are like SaaS, which are maintained by Azure DevOps (you neither  owned this agent nor able to configure it)

There are two ways which your request can be achieved

1. You can make a request in this [Github
   repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md),
   by mentioning your requirement. But I'll not recommend this one since there is no **guarantee that Microsoft** will install this software in their Hosted Agent (due to compliance/license or other policies).
2. If you really want to install any 3rd party software you should
   consider by using your own custom Agent.

Comment: Thanks.Do you know how to use a custom Agent?

Comment: @user2728409 sure, please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#install) you can install an agent in windows,mac,redhat and ubuntu